# R-convert plotly object to list

Tags: r, htmlwidgets, r-plotly, rdata

plotly_3.6.0 had function `plotly_build()` which would convert the plotly object to 'plotly_built' class which was similar to a list. 
After updating to plotly_4.7.1 it appears that this function no longer returns a 'plotly_built' object.

The built object can be converted back to plotly object using `as_widget()` which can be used for rendering in shiny application.

Is there any way to convert a plotly object to a list object?

Sample Code:

```
##generate graph and save in rdata file
library(plotly)
p <- economics %>% plot_ly(x = ~date, y = ~unemploy/pop) %>% add_lines()
pobj <- plotly_build(p)
##pobj must be of class plotly_built or list so that rdata saved file size is small and reads faster
class(pobj)
save(pobj,file = "plotlygraphs.rda")

##Load and plot graphs
x <- load("plotlygraphs.rda")
pgraph <- as_widget(pobj)
```

Comment: I have `plotly_4.7.1.9000` and `pobj` is a list of 8.

Comment: @MLavoie Can you provide sessionInfo() of your R Session. The class of pobj I am getting is : `"plotly"     "htmlwidget"`.

Comment: I am using R studio. So when I am looking in the Global Environment, I can see that `pobj` is also a list.

Comment: I see the same in Global Environment, but when I look at class(pobj), it says `"plotly" "htmlwidget"`

Comment: The underlying data structure for `pobj` and for that matter all `htmlwidgets` is a `list`.  It seems like you might be confusing [class](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html) with [data structure](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html).  

`typeof(pobj)` shows data structure while `class(pobj)` shows object class.  To remove class, you can `unclass(pobj)`.

Comment: @timelyportfolio Thanks for the clarification. But the underlying issue is that if I save a `"plotly" "htmlwidget"` object into rdata set, the object is large(~1000x more) than 'plotly_built' object that was returned by plotly_build() in plotly_3.6.0. If I have to save 100 plotly objects in rdata set and read it, it takes several minutes to load and this is connected to a shiny app which makes the app extremely slow